# Javascript AnalyserNode low frequencies (bass)

Tags: javascript, web, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have read the [MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode) about the AnalyserNode and also tried to unterstand the W3C docs.
I have a working code:

[image: Frequency Canvas]

But the very low "bass" frequencies only occupy 5 bars or so..
Is it possible to show the lower frequencies in more detail?

Comment: Code can't be run from an image, so include your code and not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not without using a larger FFT for the Analyser.  The way the math works in an FFT, the bins are spread out linearly; if you want more detail, you need to get more detail across the entire frequency spectrum (at a corresponding CPU cost, of course).

Answer (score 2):

@cwilso is basically right.

But here is an alternative that will get what you want with (quite) a bit of work and analysis and thinking.

Lowpass filter the signal to get the low frequencies you're interested in.  Decimate the signal.  Save this signal in an AudioBuffer.  Create an `OfflineAudioContext` with an `AudioBufferSource` and an `AnalyserNode`.  Run the offline context and grab the frequency data from the analyser.

As an example, let's say the context is running at 48 kHz.  We want to refine the frequencies below 3 kHz.  So, create lowpass filter with a cutoff of 3 kHz. (Using a single IIRFilter or a cascade of several biquad filters.)  Take the filtered audio and send it to an AudioWorklet or ScriptProcessor.  This node will decimate the signal by a factor of 8 (48/(2*3)) by only keeping every 16'th sample.  Gather enough data and save it away in an AudioBuffer with a sample rate of 6 kHz.  This decimation results in a signal with a bandwidth of 3 kHz at a sample rate of 6 kHz. Thus, the interesting part of the signal occupies the entire bandwidth.

Now that we have this buffer, create an offline context with a sample rate of 3 kHz.  In this context create an AudioBufferSourceNode using that buffer, and pass that to an AnalyserNode.  Get the frequency data from the  analyser.  If you used, say, 1024 points, each frequency bin is now 3 kHz/ 1024 or approx 3 Hz wide.  You've refined the low frequencies.

Comment: I would love to get some more detail about this approach. I'm still learning a lot about audio but I'm having some trouble understanding your instructions.

Comment: Ah, my answer is incorrect.  It's meant for refining the high frequencies.  I'll update it with a better answer shortly.